# How to set transactions per minute in Locust

Tags: python-3.x, load-testing, locust

I am writing a LoadTestShape Class. I want to be able to set number of transaction per minute. If I try to set it by specifying `user_count` it doesn't work because the RPS will vary cpu to cpu .

If say I want to set 1000 transaction per minute, how can we achieve that in locust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For load testing with Locust, can each locust-user reliably send a request every x seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092931/for-load-testing-with-locust-can-each-locust-user-reliably-send-a-request-every)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `constant_throughput` to control the number of requests per second.
For different time of the day I'd use a different throughput value.

Simply set the `wait_time = constant_throughput(0.1)`. Based on RPS you want you can either set the value low for less number of requests and more for more RPS.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "achieve" this in Locust is implementing [Pacing](https://www.perfmatrix.com/importance-of-pacing-think-time/), the logic is:

- You know how much time one iteration takes for one user
- If user manages to finish faster - you need to introduce some "think time" so your thread "sleeps" till the desired time
- If iteration is slower - no sleep is required.

This answer shows how you can create a [custom load shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69799323/2897748)

Alternatively you can consider switching to a load testing tool which provides such functionality, i.e. [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) with [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput)

Answer (score 1):

for this timing that's enough to add a **`LoadTestShape`** class to `locustfile.py` like the below code which I use for one of my tests you can change the number of `users` or other parameters as you want(I write a full docstring that describes each parameter in that):

```py
class StagesShape(LoadTestShape):
    """
    A simply load test shape class that has different user and spawn_rate at
    different stages.
    Keyword arguments:
        stages -- A list of dicts, each representing a stage with the following keys:
            duration -- When this many seconds pass the test is advanced to the next stage
            users -- Total user count
            spawn_rate -- Number of users to start/stop per second
            stop -- A boolean that can stop that test at a specific stage
        stop_at_end -- Can be set to stop once all stages have run.
    """

    stages = [
        {"duration": 60, "users": 3, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 6, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 9, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 12, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 15, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 18, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 21, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 24, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 27, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
        {"duration": 60, "users": 30, "spawn_rate": 0.05},
    ]

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        for stage in self.stages:
            if run_time < stage["duration"]:
                tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"])
                return tick_data

        return None
```